# RaisePropertyChanged of the whole object if inner property changed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, properties, propertychanged

i am looking for a solution to fire PropertyChanged of the whole property, if one of the inner properties changes. so here is the model:

```
public class MainStatus : ObservableObject
{
    private bool _safety;
    public bool Safety
    {
        get { return _safety; }
        set
        {
            if (_safety == value)
                return;
            _safety = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Safety");
        }
    }
    private bool _setupMode
    public bool SetupMode
    {
        get { return _setupMode; }
        set
        {
            if (_setupMode == value)
                return;
            _setupMode = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SetupMode");
        }
    }
}
```

it has some more properties (bool, int and string).

in the vm it is used like this:

```
private MainStatus _mainStatus;
public MainStatus MainStatus
{
    get { return _mainStatus; }
    set
    {
        if (_mainStatus == value)
            return;
        _mainStatus = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MainStatus");
    }
}
```

i can bind to the inner properties like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MainStatus.Safety}" Value="true">
```

this all works fine. but i need to send the whole MainStatus to other VMs, if one of the inner property changes. so i changed the property like the this:

```
public MainStatus MainStatus
{
    get { return _mainStatus; }
    set
    {
        if (_mainStatus == value)
            return;
        _mainStatus = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MainStatus");
        Messenger.Default.Send<MainStatusMessage>(new MainStatusMessage() { MainStatus = _mainStatus });
    }
}
```

but this does not work. it seems like the PropertyChanged for the `MainStatus` is never fired if one of the inner properties changes. how can i fix that?

Comment: if it's not fired than it means that your `PropertyChanged` EventHandler is null, that's due to the Bindings not being resolved. Just as a test subscribe your `ViewModel` to the `Model`s PropertyChanged Event and see if you can pick up the changes then.

Comment: Your `Messenger.Default.Send` will only be called if you assign a _new_ instance of a `MainStatus` class to your property `MainStatus` of the vm. It won't be called if you just change any of the inner MainStatus properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your VM, you could subscribe to `Mainstatus.PropertyChanged` event something like:

```
 this.MainStatus.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(MainStatus_PropertyChanged);

 //..........
 void MainStatus_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     RaisePropertyChanged("MainStatus");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I uderstand the question you want to raise the property changed events for ALL properties on a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, this can be achieved by calling the event handler with a NULL instead of the string containing the property name:

e.g. RaisePropertyChanged(null) would raise both Safety and SetUpMode on the MainStatus class defined above.